# how c++ implements the polymorphism internally?

Tags: c++, oop

Respected Sir!

i should tell you that what i know and what i don't know about the asked question so that you can address the weak area of my understanding.

i know that c++ implements the polymorphism by using the Vtable which is array of pointers 
each pointer points to the virtual function of the class, each class in the hierarchy has a vtable. now suppose i have the following class

```
class person
{
    char name[20];
public:
    person(char* pname)
    {
        strcpy(name,pname);
    }

    virtual void show()
    {
        cout<<"inside person show method, Name: "<<name;
    }
};

class teacher:public person
{
     int scale;

     teacher(char*pname, int s):person(pname)
     {
         scale=s;
     }

     void show()
     {
         cout<<"inside the teacher show method, Scale: "<<scale;
     }
};
```

now suppose i write in main program

```
person *ptr;
ptr=new teacher(16,"Zia");
ptr->show();
```

now i am confuse at this point, the call will go to the show function of the base class, now as it is a virtual function so it inturn calls the approprite function. i know i am wrong here. i am confused that what would be the sequence of calls. What is the role of Vtable and how it works please elaborate.

Comment: Zia, please learn Markdown syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Zia ur Rahman: have a look at the qn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092283/how-functions-are-resolved-by-compiler , that explains when compiler makes a polymorphic call and when it is going to be direct call..

Comment: This is __NOT__ usfull inofrmation to know at your level. Concentrate more on the language and how it works not how it is implemented. This is the kind of exoteric information you need to know only when writting compilers. Eventually you will get to know the basics but like all the examples below show, most people only know the real basics not the details that they really need to know.

Comment: @Martin some people needs to understand the plumbing in order to use the bathroom. I know I do. Besides, knowing the consequences of the virtual keyword is important for a C++ developer, even if he does not write compilers.

Comment: @Vincent Let me know if you ever intend coming round my place - I'll have a mop  and  and a bucket ready.

Comment: @Neil :) Of course I did not mean I need to understand every plumbing wherever I go to the bathroom. Enough with analogies, I just think this is important to understand how things works in programming, specifically what the difference is between a virtual and a non-virtual method call.

Comment: @Vincent: Yes understanding the difference between virtual and normal methods is important and this is a language level construct (even understanding the cost difference may be useful [realistically 0]). But needing to understand the implementation details is not required or useful to 99.99% of C++ engineers (or even realistic for 98% of C++ developers (It’s like asking parents to make informed decisions about required brain surgery on their children [ie they can have a basic understanding but unless they are brain surgeons there is no realistic way they can understand what is happening])).

Comment: @Martin: Just because the original asker doesn't need to know the answer doesn't mean the more advanced people can't benefit from it having been asked & answered

Comment: @Narfanator: In theorey that is a great idea. Unfortunately the people that actually know how to do this already know, and are not going to answer the question here as this topic is so way complicated that the only way to do any justice to the subject is write an article in Dr Dobs (or other reputable trade Journal). As a result the posted replies are provided by people that don't actually know the real problems and you only get a generalised answer. If you are in the 2% that can actually grasp all the problems (check the gcc source) then get a job as compiler engeneer (good pay).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should draw attention to Stanley B. Lippman's book "[Inside C++ object model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)".

Lets look for internal presentation for your classes:

Virtual Table for person and teacher

```
|---------------|  +---> |------------------------|
|  name         |  |     | "type_info" for person |
|---------------|  |     |------------------------|
|__vptr__person |--+     | "person::~person"      |
|---------------|        |------------------------|
person p;                | "person::show"         |
                         |------------------------|

|----------------|  +---> |-------------------------|
|person subobject|  |     | "type_info" for teacher |
|----------------|  |     |-------------------------|
|__vptr__teacher |--+     | "teacher::~teacher"     |
|----------------|        |-------------------------|
teacher t;                | "teacher::show"         |
                          |-------------------------|
```

In general, we don't know the exact type of the object ptr addresses at each invocation of show(). We do know, however, that through ptr we can access the virtual table associated with the object's class.

Although we don't know which instance of show() to invoke, we know that each instance's address is contained in slot 2.

This information allows the compiler to internally transform the call into

```
( *ptr->vptr[ 2 ] )( ptr );
```

In this transformation, vptr represents the internally generated virtual table pointer inserted within each class object and 2 represents show()'s assigned slot within the virtual table associated with the Point hierarchy. The only thing we need to do in runtime is compute ptr's dynamic type (and appropriate vtable) using RTTI.

Comment: He didn't make his destructor virtual though

Comment: Yep. I think Zia ur Rahman's aswer would be: "Dear Sir its not the whole code , i only posted the code which has problem.";)

Comment: ooooo yes sir! you are right , i post only related code. because people hate to read lengthy code. And yes your answer is completly helpful, thank you.

Comment: Simply having a function index wouldn't work for multiple inheritance, would it?

Comment: RTTI has nothing to do with the vtable. Try disabling RTTIs in your compiler and your virtual methods will still resolve correctly. RTTI is only used to dynamically store the object type at runtime in addition to fields.

Answer (score 11):

Since `show` is declared `virtual` in the `person` class, the compiler will not hard-code the method call like it would do for a non-virtual method, it will instead compile a lookup in the V-table in order to retrieve the right function.

So `ptr->show()` will be compiled as `ptr->vtable['show']()` which means "search the function pointer that corresponds to method `show` and execute it".

Since at runtime, `ptr` points to an object of class `teacher`, the vtable slot for `show` contains a pointer to the method `show` in the class `teacher`. That is why the right method is executed.

Actually, lookup in the V-table is not done using strings but using numeric method identifiers in order to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 6):

C++ language doesn't define polymorphism implementations, not even the `vtable`. That's up to the compilers.
One possible implementation is the one mentioned by [Vincent Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171081/how-c-implements-the-polymorphism-internally/2171110#2171110).

Answer (score 3):

The Standard says nothing about how to implements the polymorphism. One class one vtbl and one object one vptr is the most popular way.
I hope the following pseudocode would be helpful.

```
typedef struct {
    void (*show)(void* self);
    // more

} person_vtbl;

typedef struct {
      person_vtbl* vtbl;
      char         name[20];
} person;

void person_show(void* self) {
      cout<<"inside ... "<<static_cast<person*>(self)->name;
}
// more

static person_vtbl person_vtbl_ = { &person_show }; // vtbl for person class

void person_ctor(void* self, char const* name) {
      person* p = static_cast<person*>(self);
      strcpy(p->name, name);
      p->vtbl   = &person_vtbl  // vptr of person object
}

typedef struct {
    person base;
    int    scale;
} teacher;

void teacher_show(void* self) {
      cout<<"inside the tearch ... "<<static_cast<teacher*>(self)->scale;
}
static person_vtbl teacher_vtbl_ = { &teacher_show };

void teacher_ctor(void* self, char const* name, int s) {
      teacher* t = static_cast<teacher*>(self);
      person_ctor(&t->base, name);     // construct base part
      t->scale   = s;                  // construct teacher part
      t->vtbl    = &teacher_vtbl_;     // vptr of teacher object
}

// construct teacher :
// person* ptr = new teacher("Zia", 16);

teacher* tmp = static_cast<teacher*>( malloc( sizeof *tmp );
teacher_ctor(tmp, "Zia", 16);  // vptr of tmp points to teacher_vtbl_
person* ptr = &tmp->base;

// call virtual function though pointer
// ptr->show()

ptr->vptr->show(ptr); // call teacher_show(ptr);
```

Comment: What is "t->vtbl"? Actually class of t doesn't have member `vtbl`.