# How would you call the kind of polymorphism introduced by arrays in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, oop, polymorphism

AFAIK at the infrastructure (CLI/.Net/Mono) level there is a single type to represent arrays: `System.Array`.

Physically this is a linear sequence of values, but logically they can be considered are organized in more than one dimension.

At the language level (e.g. C#) this logical view benefits from some syntactic sugar:

```
2D: T[,]
3D: T[,,]
42D: T[,,,...,,,]
```

There is an obvious **parametric polymorphism** as behind a 1D array for example can hide more than one type of array:

```
Array of integers: int[]
Array of strings references: string[]
Array of objects references: object[]
```

But how would you describe the **structural polymorphism**, the fact that the array can have multiple dimensions?

At the infrastructure level this is no more a part of the type system, and is only a logical view, so I think there is no polymorphism at all.

But at the language level it might be considered as some kind of inclusion polymorphism as all the arrays are logically presented as different types inheriting from a common base class.

Any input and correction is welcome.

Comment: I'm not aware of any situation where the programmer can make use of this, so I wouldn't call it polymorphism at all; your 42D array never takes on another array form in a program in the way that the array can be treated as class `Object`.

Comment: @JohnC: AFAIK you can have a method that takes a `System.Array` and dumps its values according to its dimensionality. This is clearly polymorphism. And probably some kind of inclusion polymorphism.

Comment: Array types exist at the CLR level as well. Not just at the C# level. The two type systems are not exactly congruent, though. The array dimensionality is not just a logical concept. You can't cast an array to a different dimensionality. The dimensions are stored in the object and are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Array` class has an essentially-infinite family of derivatives, one for each element type and possible number of dimensions.  Because arrays predate generics, they have a special "quasi-hardcoded" means of accomplishing this.  Basically, the .NET Framework contains a special hard-coded "recipe" so that given a base-item type and a number of dimensions, it can generate a type, derived from `System.Array`, which will act as an array with that specified base-item type and dimensionality.  Further, because of the way array covariance works, arrays can behave as though they implement interfaces which are not actually part of their class, in ways that no other type can.  For example, because a reference of type `Cat[]` is also a reference of type `Animal[]`, `Cat[]` implements not only `IList<Cat>` but also `IList<Animal>`.

There is no mechanism via which any type other than `System.Array` can support such covariance, nor is there any way via which user code can define a family of classes such that for any integer `n` there will be a derivative whose `get` method takes `n` parameters.  The generic types in .NET can do many things which arrays cannot, but since arrays are implemented via a mechanism other than the generic type facility, they can support some features that facility cannot.

Comment: So at the .Net level we have some **dynamic inclusion polymorphism**: subtypes are generated on the fly?

Comment: @Pragmateek: I don't know the exact details, and they probably differ between .NET versions, but arrays, delegates, strings, nullables, and structures all have some special "magic" in the Runtime which allows them to do things other types cannot.  Some of the "magic" could perhaps have been exposed to user types, thus eliminating the need for the types themselves to behave magically (e.g. the system could have allowed structures to be tagged to indicate whether they should satisfy a `struct` constraint, and had boxing and unboxing instructions chain to virtual methods in `ValueType` whose...

Comment: ...default implementations were equivalent to the present box/unbox instructions.  That would have allowed not only unboxing an `int` to an `int?` but also to a `long` [if `long`'s unbox method included provision for that]).  Of course, if generics had been included from the start, many aspects of .NET may look very different, but it's also possible it never would have gotten off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

All derived array types descend from `System.Array` and override the appropriate methods.  Arrays are a bit special, though, in the sense that there is baked-in support in the **CLR** in the form of **IL opcodes** that interact directly with concrete array types.  Still, though, this is the same kind of base class polymorphism as with other classes, at least when accessed via the Array class.

However, arrays are not actually 'polymorphic' in dimensionality in the sense you're thinking.  A particular array instance is assigned a particular dimensionality when it's constructed and it can only be used with that dimensionality.  This occurs both at the op code level and the GetValue methods.  The IList implementation for 'Item' (the indexer) also only supports a single dimension; if you attempt to use it on a multi-dimensional array, you'll get an ArgumentException.

---

Also, just in case it's not clear, the `A[x,y]` syntax is actually not syntactic sugar.  Multi-dimensional arrays are actually excluded from the built-in CLR support and instead are accessed via methods.  This compiles to something like the following IL:

```
Ldloc A //(load array A onto the operation stack)
Ldloc x //(load value of variable x onto the operation stack)
Ldloc y //(load value of variable y onto the operation stack)
call int32[,]::Get(int, int) //(return a 4-byte signed integer from the array at indices [x,y], putting the result onto the operation stack)
```

You can compare this to the same for a single-dimensional array `A[x]`:

```
Ldloc A //(load array A onto the operation stack)
Ldloc x //(load value of variable x onto the operation stack)
Ldelem_I4 //(return the 4-byte signed integer from the array at index [x] and put the result onto the operation stack)
```

Comment: I don't think the interface `IList` has any implementation.

Answer (score -1):

> But how would you describe the structural polymorphism, the fact that the array can have multiple dimensions?

Three points:

- At the language level, multidimensional arrays would qualify as internal polymorphism
- Since multidimensional arrays can be emulated with associative arrays or lists, it need not depend on a specific data structure
- Since multidimensional arrays can be created at runtime, it need not depend on type checking

**References**

- [Create a two-dimensional array at runtime](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Create_a_two-dimensional_array_at_runtime)
- [OO Uber-Zealotry Considered Silly](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1090#comment-11719)
- [how c++ implements the polymorphism internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171081/)
- [Refactoring a Switch Statement](http://tmont.com/blargh/2011/11/refactoring-a-switch-statement)
- [C2 Wiki: External Polymorphism](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExternalPolymorphism)